# Transform a table in SQL

Tags: sql, ssis

This might be a beginner's question but I don't know what's the terminology for the transformation so I am unable to get useful search results so far.

The input table is like:

```
ID, FromCity, ToCity, ViaCity
1, New York, Chicago, NULL
2, New York, Los Angeles, Chicago
3, Chicago, Boston, NULL
```

And the desired output is

```
City, FromCount, ToCount, ViaCount
New York, 2, 0, 0
Chicago, 1, 1, 1
Los Angeles, 0, 1, 0
Boston, 0, 1, 0
NULL, 0, 0, 2
```

The list of city names should be generated from the first table, i.e. there isn't an existing table for it.

I would prefer to build an indexed view but if the query is too complex and SSIS can make it easy I can use SSIS too.

Comment: `PIVOT` is the term you are looking `:)`

Comment: @JW웃 Thanks for the quick suggestion:) I just looked at PIVOT and seems it's not changing the type of row object, maybe I'm missing something. Can you help me with the query I seek in the question?

Comment: is the correct value of `NULL` in `ViaCount` is 1 or 2?

Comment: @JW웃 2, typo updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that is database independent:

```
select city, sum(fromcity) as fromcity, sum(tocity) as tocity, sum(via) as via
from ((select fromcity as city, 1 as fromcity, 0 as tocity, 0 a via
       from t
      ) union all
      (select tocity, 0, 1, 0
       from t
      ) union all
      (select via, 0, 0, 1
       from t
      )
     ) t
group by city
```